# How to update current date with timestamp using ORM query

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I want to update DeletedAt column in a table using the doctrine ORM query like below, but it is throwing me an error

```php
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->update()
    ->set('deletedAt', new \DateTime('now'))
    ->from($this->entityNamespace, 'u')
    ->where("u.tenant Id  = $tenantId");

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

It is throwing an error

> Method Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: The error is clear, there is no way to convert the DateTime to string automatically. Try `->set('deletedAt', (new \DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`

Comment: instead of removing the timestamp and formatting, we can use **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()** like    `->set('r.deletedAt', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')`

Comment: It's working now :)